# NLPのための、pytermextractパッケージがインストールできない

Tags: python, python3

http://gensen.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/pytermextract/
上のリンクを参考に、デスクトップ上でファイルをダウンロードし解凍し、コマンドプロンプトから

```
python setup.py install
```

と行ったのですが、そのようなファイルはないとエラーがでてしまいます。
何が原因なのかさっぱりわからないのですが、どのようにすれば解決するのでしょうか。そもそも解凍した、pytermextract-0_01の中にあるsetup.pyをダブルクリックしても開けないのですが（それは当たり前？）。

追記.1】エラーは以下のようになります。
    C:\Users\username>python setup.py install
    python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

追記.2】

[image: Desktop上にset.pyがあるが、コマンドプロンプトからインストールされない図です]

Comment: 質問文に、出てきたエラーメッセージをそのままコピー＆ペーストして頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ファイルをデスクトップに保存/解凍したのであれば、フォルダは以下のパスの様になるはずです。
この中に`setup.py`ファイルが含まれています。
(エクスプローラのアドレス欄にフォーカスを移してみてください)

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\pytermextract-0_01
```

一方で、コマンドプロンプトを開いた直後のカレントディレクトリ(自分自身がいる場所)は、デフォルトだと以下の様にログインユーザーのホームディレクトリにいるので、**目的のファイルがある場所まで移動してから**インストール用のコマンドを実行する必要があります。

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\
```

`cd`コマンドでフォルダを移動

```
C:\Users\USERNAME>cd Desktop\pytermextract-0_01
```

念のため`dir`コマンドでファイルの一覧を表示(setup.pyがあるか確認)

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\pytermextract-0_01>dir
```

インストールを実行

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\pytermextract-0_01>python setup.py install
```

Comment: 自分もディレクトリの位置を気にしながら行ったのですが、やはり上手くいかないです。そのときのスクショを追記で置かせていただきます。